# Displacement Vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, reference-frames, vectors, displacement

I am trying to understand how multiple dimensions will affect displacement.

I'm given the initial velocity:

$-2.5\frac{m}{s}\hat{\textbf{i}}$.

The acceleration is:

$3.5\frac{m}{s^2}\hat{\textbf{i}} + 2.75\frac{m}{s^2}\hat{\textbf{j}}$.

I'm asked to find the displacement and velocity vectors at time 5.1s.

At first, I just calculated the magnitude of both the acceleration and velocity vectors, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Should I instead use the displacement formula on both the x components and the y components?

Is it okay to just use the magnitudes? I ask because it seemed like that would not be okay for calculating the velocity vectors. Instead, I thought I would have to use the motion formula on both the x component and the y component. Is this also true for displacement?

Comment: How would you propose to calculate velocity and displacement vectors, which in your case have two components, using only the velocity and acceleration magnitudes?

Comment: (Should I instead use the displacement formula on both the x components and the y components?) Yes you must as the components of acceleration in one direction do not affect that in the perpendicular one.

Comment: @Ramanujan_π Thank you, that's what I needed clarification on